# Executing a Cypher query on Neo4j using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, neo4j

I am trying to make an Ajax call with jQuery to a Neo4j Server, both on the same machine, but I keep getting errors in the response.

This is how I wrote the ajax call:

```js
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    accepts: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "query" : "MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 1", "params": {} })
});
```

When I execute this code, in FireBug I see:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher"
```

And in the response to the POST request I find the following body:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body><p><pre>WebApplicationException
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.HtmlFormat.serializeMapping(HtmlFormat.java:348)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.serializeMapping(RepresentationFormat.java:73)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:39)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:215)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:147)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:130)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:67)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:101)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
at org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)</pre></p></body></html>
```

These are the response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin...      *
Content-Length                      1065
Content-Type                        text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server                              Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
```

When I do the same request in Chrome's Advanced Rest Client, I do get the desired response.

How can I make my ajax call so Neo4j will give me the results from the Cypher query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the snippet you've supplied a more complex `Accepts` header is sent that Neo4j cannot deal with. I've used the following snippets:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    accepts: { json: "application/json" },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "query" : "MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 1", "params": {} })
 });
```

Omitting both, `accepts` and `dataType` seems to work as well:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "query" : "MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 1", "params": {} })
 });
```